# Codeng - Korean translation community for Stack Overflow

Tags: app, website

### Screenshot

Home & Search
[image]

### About

This website is made for Stack users who are **unfamiliar to English** (Korean developers).
Anyone can translate Stack Overflow questions into Korean for others unfamiliar to English.

[How to use]

1. Login using Stack Exchange authentication OAuth.
2. Search Stack questions by keywords in English or Korean.
3. Add comments in Korean.
4. Add translation in Korean.

[There are 3 translation input types]

1. literal translation - translate using automatic Markdown format same as English source format word by word.
2. liberal(summary) translation - interprete English question into Korean summary text with translator's opinion.
3. title only translation - Only Korean titles can help people also.

#### License

free to use.

#### Link to App

http://www.codeng.co.kr

#### Platform

browsers that support HTML5

### Contact

Creator: Carl Shin (codeng.kr@gmail.com)

### Code

using Python, Django, Bootstrap, jQuery, Markdown

### History

10/19/2014 - v0.3: simplified search main

9/07/2014 - v0.2

9/14/2014 - simplified home and search results and added title translation input ui in search results.